# How the best use Multilanguage in views

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with translated string. There are value for every language and languageId own rows.
I haven't problem with procedure or function because I can use parameter @LanguageId.

But I have a problem with views!

For example:

```
SELECT 
  a.ID, 
b.Text as TypeText, 
b.TranslateId as TypeTranslateId,
c.Text as CategoryText, 
c.TranslateId CategoryTranslateId,
d.Text as SourceText,
d.TranslateId as SourceTranslateId
FROM base a
LEFT JOIN enumB b a.TypeId = b.Id
LEFT JOIN enumC c a.CategoryId = c.Id
LEFT JOIN enumD d a.SourceId = d.Id
```

I Can join all languages but I'm not sure this is good way.

If I refined each language in the view, the rows in the output would multiply according to the number of language sets.
If I pull only the key, it will then be hard to perform in the application condition on the like.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using an inline table value function, rather than a view? Then you can parametrise the query.

Comment: Side note, all your `JOIN`s are missing the `ON` keyword.

Comment: You can use a parameterized query with a `WHERE` clause that filters the view's results. You're probably doing this in a stored procedure or functino already

Comment: I fail to see the use case. Do you really need to see the Chinese translation of a text when you are working with Romanian? I would guess that only a handful of languages can be helpful at any given time.